# How to make a catch-all category in Pelican?

Tags: pelican

How can I make a page that lists all article titles (similar to [WP Sitemap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sitemap-page/))?

Titles only, no summaries, grouped by categories or chronologically. I know about the sitemap plugin but it only outputs xml or txt.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the feature is called "archive" and is enabled in `pelicanconf.py` by

```
ARCHIVES_SAVE_AS = 'pages/archives.html'
MENUITEMS = [ ('All posts', '/pages/archives.html') ]
```

The exact layout of the listing page is taken from `templates/archives.html` of the theme.